# Need Assistance With JavaScript ImageSlider - What Am I Doing Wrong?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var imageCounter = 1;

Function change() { 
    var image = doc.getElementById("image2");

    if( imageCounter==1 ) { 
        image.src = '2.jpg'; 
        imageNumber = 2; 
    } 
    else if( imageCounter==2 { 
        image.src = '3.jpg'; 
       imageNumber = 3; 
    } else {
      imageCounter = 1; 
    }   
    setInterval("change()",6500);
```

```
 <button id="knapp1" type="button" onclick="change()">==></button>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I have been trying to understand what I'm failing.

Comment: Whats the problem/ error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heii
copy this code

```
    <html>
    <head>

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boss.css">


    <script language="JavaScript">
    var i = 0;
    var path = new Array();

    // LIST OF IMAGES
    path[0] = "1.jpg";
    path[1] = "2.jpg";
    path[2] = "3.jpg";

    function change()
    {
       document.slide.src = path[i];

       if(i < path.length - 1) i++; else i = 0;
       setTimeout("swapImage()",6500);
    }
    window.onload=change;
    </script>


    </head>

    <body>

     <center>
      <img src="1.jpg" border="1" name="slide" height="300" width="750" id="image2"/> 
     </center>

     <button id="knapp1" type="button" onclick="change()">==></button> 
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you have

`Function change()`

with a capital F.

It should be `function change()`

another thing is that `imageNumber` is not declared. Im not sure what it is or what its used for but just do
`var imageNumber;`

`setInterval("function()",6000);`

It should **not** be in quotes.

`setInterval(change(),6000);`

Next thing, is that if you are running this off your computer, it will not find `3.jpg`
Instead you have to give the complete file location of the image.

One last thing: on your function you are missing a curly bracket at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that sometimes you assign to `imageCounter` and sometimes you assign to `imageNumber`. Decide on one name and use it consistently.

Also, `function` does not start with a capital letter. JavaScript is case-sensitive.